# Session after redirect ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am pretty new to ASP.Net and I am testing how the sessions work after a redirect. The problem is that I am not able to retrieve my data after i redirected.

code form 1:

```
Session["person"] = person; // Object
Session["relation"] = relation; // Object
Response.Redirect("~/Fom2.aspx", false); // found online this has to be false to keep session token
```

code form 2:

```
Person person = (Person)(Session["person"]); //null
Relation relation = (Relation)(Session["relation"]); //null
```

Can anybody help me? Thnx

Answer (score 0):

The string in `Session["string"]` has to be exactly the same. Remove the space from `Session["person "]` in form 2 so it is `Session["person"]`

Comment: Sry, i failed my copy paste, i still get null as a esult doh

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? According to [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_) there was a Session bug in an older version.

Comment: .NET 4.6.1 is the version i am using

Comment: Is the code you posted from a controller or a view?